# Force of an accelerating ball?

Tags: forces, newtonian-gravity, mass, collision

By Newton's second law, we know that $F=ma$. If I were to drop a ball from some height, it would accelerate to the ground with gravitational acceleration. But if I were to drop the same ball from a greater height, why would it hit the ground harder, with greater force? In both circumstances, doesn't the ball have the same acceleration and mass?

Answer (score 1):

Newtons second law actually states that force on a body is the "rate of change of momentum". So if a ball is dropped from a greater height, it has more velocity as compared to it being dropped from lesser height as it's accelerating  , and hence requires more time to reach the same spot by covering a larger distance. Now the velocity of the ball becomes zero when it reaches the earth(since the ball is not heavy/fast enough to affect earth's surface's momentum significantly, and so

$$F=\frac{\Delta mv}{dt}=\frac{mv}{dt}$$

That is, in a very short time(time taken by the ball to stop moving on coming with contact with surface it's rate of change of momentum is directly proportional to $v$, hence, a larger force acts.

Answer (score 0):

At the exact moment of impact, is the ball still in free-fall?  Is there not a change in momentum due to something other than gravity during the impact?

The velocity changes over some (probably very small) duration as the ball stops.  This will result in a force much greater than the weight of the ball during the impact.

But once the ball completely stops moving the only force from the ball is it's weight.  So F = ma over the entire duration.

Answer (score 0):

> But if I were to drop the same ball from a greater height, why would it hit the ground harder, with greater force?

Yes, it's right. Because when the ball falls from a greater height it has more velocity for acceleration and so it has more momentum.

Suppose, at first the ball was released from a height $h_1$ and it gained a velocity $v_1$ just before touching the ground.

After again the ball is released from a height of $h_2$ and gains velocity $v_2$ before touching the ground.

If, $h_2 > h_1$ then $v_2 > v_1$

Suppose for the first condition the momentum is $p_1$ and the second condition momentum is $p_2$.

Then, $p_2 > p_1$

When the ball hits the ground, it stops within a very short time which is equal for both cases. Suppose the time is $∆t$

Then, $$\frac {p_2} {∆t} > \frac {p_1} {∆t}$$

According to Newton's second law, rate of change in momentum is directly proportional to the force. We know that the momentum of the ball becomes 0 after collision.

So,

$$\frac {p_2 - 0} {∆t} > \frac {p_1 - 0} {∆t}$$

Or, $$F_2 > F_1$$

Where $F_1$ is the exerted force on the ball by ground for the first condition and $F_2$ is the exerted force on the ball by ground for the second condition. According to Newton's third law, every action has the equal and opposite reaction. Thus, the ball exerts much force when is dropped from greater height (which is the second condition).

Hope this helps.